# Send id from one table to another automatically in form with ForeignKey in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

#HELP in python (DJANGO 4)

I send this message here because I have not been able to find an answer elsewhere.
Currently I’m on a project where I have to create a booking form.
The goal is that when the user submit the Reservation form, I send the data in BDD, and I retrieve the user's id by a relation (ForeignKey).
And my difficulty is in this point precisely, when I send my form in BDD I recover the information, except the id of the user…
I did a Foreignkey relationship between my 2 tables and I see the relationship in BDD but I don’t receive the id of the User table, but null in the place….
Does anyone of you know how to help me please?
Thank you all.

--My model.py --

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    fullName = models.CharField('Nom Complet', max_length=250, null=True)
    adress = models.CharField('Adresse', max_length=100, null=True)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField('Code Postal', null=True)
    city = models.CharField('Vile', max_length=100, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField('Email', max_length=250, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField('Telephone', max_length=20, null=False)
    date = models.CharField('Date', max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    hour = models.CharField('Heure', max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    message = models.TextField('Message', null=True)
    accepted = models.BooleanField('Valide', null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('Date Creation', auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField('Date Mise Jour', auto_now=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

def __str__(self):
    return self.fullName
```

-- my views.py --

```
    @login_required()
def user_new_reservation(request, pk=None):
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReservationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Votre réservation a bien été envoyé!')
            return redirect('reservation:user_reservation', pk=request.user.id)
    else:
        form = ReservationForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'reservation/new_reservation.html', context)
```

-- My Form.py --

```
class ReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Reservation
    fields = [
        'fullName',
        'adress',
        'zip_code',
        'city',
        'email',
        'phone',
        'date',
        'hour',
        'message',
    ]
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your form.save use:

```
user = form.save(commit=False)
user.user = request.user
user.save()
```

**user**=your field name in your model

**request user**= in django when you use authentication you can access some of information based on request like user and other

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this method does not work.
I have the following message ( save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user' ) and I can't understand the reason why he does not want to take the user..

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answers